# Can I couple NetLogo with another programme?

Tags: r, netlogo, coupling

I'm wondering if it is possible to couple NetLogo with another programme?

My aim is to somehow couple NetLogo with a hydraulic model so that the results are input into NetLogo as the hydraulic model carries out simulations (in real time). I'm aware this can be done in Repast but I have no experience in Java whereas I'm comfortable with Logo, so i'm exploring other options first.

My first thoughts are perhaps to somehow use the R-extension for NetLogo to facilitate this...

Comment: see https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Controlling-API and https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Extensions-API

Answer (score 2):

The NLRX package links R to NetLogo and is very useful for setting up experiments as you would through behaviourspace. Here's the [paper](https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/2041-210X.13286) and the associated github [website](https://github.com/ropensci/nlrx/).